# ¿Cómo recuperar acentos codificados en JavaScript para poder usarlos en PHP? (%C3%AD)

Tags: javascript, php5

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna función o un método que me permita recuperar los acentos que fueron codificados en JavaScript para usarlos en PHP.

Lo que he hecho es lo siguiente:

**DOCUMENTO HTML**

```
<form id="formulario"  method='post' ENCTYPE='multipart/form-data' accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <select name="Provincias" id="provincias" ></select>  
<button type="submit" id="search">Busca</button>
</form>
```

**DOCUMENTO JS**

```
$("#search").on("click", function(e)
{   
    e.preventDefault();     

    if(!valida())
        return;     

    var datos_del_formulario = $("#formulario").serialize();
    alert(datos_del_formulario );


    $.post("./php/buscar.php",  datos_del_formulario, function(respuesta)
    {   
        alert(respuesta);
    });
});
```

**DOCUMENTO PHP**

```
echo $_GET['Provincias'];
```

Lo que está ocurriendo es que por ejemplo la palabra **"Andalucía"** se ha codificado de esta forma **Andaluc%C3%ADa** y necesito que esté correctamente escrita para poder hacer consultas en MySQL con PHP.

Comment: ¿Has probado con la funcion `utf8_encode` en php?  https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: No, no he probado... voy a hacerlo ahora. y te digo que tal va... gracias!!

Comment: No funcionó... pero gracias igualmente!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) utiliza el [código URL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_porciento). Para decodificar la cadena, usa [rawurldecode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.rawurldecode.php)

```
<?php
echo rawurldecode('Andaluc%C3%ADa'); // Muestra: Andalucía
```

Comment: Es perfecto, muchas gracias!!